# How to hide a button in reusable ViewController in PageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of 3 instances of vc (orderedViewControllers = [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC]). And I reuse the vc changing pictures for these instances. I also need to hide a button of the last vc. I try to do it like this but it doesn’t work. Are there any other ways to hide a button of the last vc?

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if orderedViewControllers.last == thirdVC {
            thirdVC.orangeButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try creating a bool variable in the forwarding view controller and setting that value to the button AFTER the view did load there.

Comment: All viewControllers have the same Class?

Comment: thnx @ElTomato ! Your advice has solved my problem!)

Comment: yeah, all three vc instances have the same class